# Avoid global's inside of a function

Tags: php, function, dependency-injection, global-variables

I'm making a forum system in PHP, and I'm stumbling accross an annoying problem when writing the code to insert a new topic. I'm using a bunch of objects, like User, Post and Topic, all of them take a PDO object in their constructor (dependency injection).

**Note** I know that similar questions have been asked before, but all the answers that I found recommand using dependency injection, and in this case I don't find it very clear or convenient to use, since there would be at least 3, sometimes more, dependencies to inject into many different functions.

Currently, when I'm making a new topic (thread), it's calling a parsing page that does all the check : user has to be logged in, title has to be at least 3 characters long, and so on. To avoid nested `if`'s, I'm wrapping all that code inside a function, so I can just use `return` to get out when something goes wrong.

The problem with this is that my function doesn't have access to the User, Post and Topic objects that are created in an `init` page, required on all pages automatically.

I know about `dependency injection`, but it doesn't make sense to me to pass four different objects as parameters to my function.

Here's a sample of code for that `newTopic` function, which is inside the parsing page mentionned above :

```
if(!empty($_POST['newTopic']))
    newTopic();

function newTopic()
{
    //Check that the user is connected
    if(!$User->isConnected())
        return false;

    //Other checks ...
    $Topic->new($author, $title, $content);
}
```

Of course, the `$User` and `$Topic`  objects aren't accessible inside of a function. I can either pass it as a parameter, or use `global` . I know that the usage of `global`  is not recommanded, however I don't think that passing four different objects to each functions is a much better practice ..

**The question** What's the best thing to do in this case? Pass my objects as parameters to the `newTopic` function? Use `global`'s ? Use nested `if`'s instead of a function?

Comment: My vote is for dependency injection. Also the way you are coding is mixing functions and classes, why not have a Topic class which has a create method? (this would still use dependency injection but at least would make it OOP and consistent)

Comment: @user3238482 At the moment I'm using the parse page with the `newTopic`  function to validate the user input, display the errors message and all, and the ` Topic`  class is responsible for accessing the DB mainly. The same problem happens if I do the validation inside of the ` Topic`  class, since it doesn't have access to the ` User`  class either (to check if the user is logged in for example).

Comment: If you really dont want your functions to access the objects directly then you could just pass though the values e.g $logged_in = $User->isConnected(); and then: newTopic($logged_in) inside the function just check if(!$logged_in) etc...

Answer (score 0):

Might be a good spot for a builder.

```
$builder = new TopicBulder()->setAuthor($author)->setTitle($title)->setContent($content)->getTopic();
```

Where TopicBuilder is a class with each method returning and reference to $this.

```
class TopicBuilder {
private $topic;

function __construct() {
    $this->topic = new Topic();
}

public function setAuthor($author) {
    $this->topic->setAuthor($author);
    return $this;
}

....

public function getTopic() {
    return $this->topic.
}
```

}

Or something cleaner then that ;)

Answer (score 0):

You may separate logic of a new topic creation, such as checks, maybe DB operations and so on, and creation of a new object of Topic class. Note, that creation of a Topic object is necessary means it should be persistent at once. Topic class may only be a struct for topic data.